# Encoded Image does not showed up in native iPhone mail app

Tags: java, base64, mandrill

I have a template in `Mandrill` Which I am assessing through a Java Client. I am sending `Base64` encoded image to the `Mandrill` ,which is sent successfully and also visible inside `Gmail` . But the same image is not showing up in iOS native `Mail`  app .

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the reason for this. So , I ended up uploading the images to the server and sending the URL of the image inside the template to Mandrill rather than the encoded one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The I saw this, include the img tag as the answer says, and it worked fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703026/1778068